# Как пул потоков определяет продолжение кода для IRP пакета?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, асинхронность

После прочтения статей об асинхронности: https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/, http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/3304, задался вопросом:

Когда `IRP` пакет становится в очередь и поток из пула потоков ввода/вывода собирается обработать его, то как поток узнает, КАКОЙ код нужно выполнить (т.е. какой ИМЕННО код, являющийся продолжением асинхронной операции, нужно выполнить)? `IRP` пакет содержит эту информацию?

Comment: Вы что-то очень сильно все упростили. Между IRP и непосредственном кодом еще очень много уровней, и, естественно, IRP-пакет ничего не знает о коде и он не обрабатывается потоком из пула потоков. Прочитайте статью по первой ссылке внимательнее.

Comment: @andreycha прочитал. Тогда вопрос: откуда APC знает об уведомлении НУЖНОЙ задачи? Про мое упрощение: у Рихтера написано, что поток обрабатывает IRP пакет...

Comment: @andreycha и все же у IRP пакета есть свойство типа HANDLE, указывающее на IOCP поток...